# I have a c++ program running on linux, is it possible to have it periodically store state snapshots in shared memory for post-crash recovery?

Tags: c++, linux, shared-memory

I'm not sure how to go about it as I've seen examples of shared memory used for interprocess communication. I was wondering if I could leverage it from within a server to take, say, periodic snapshots of certain objects and dump them in some format in shared memory which..if my program crashes..could be retrieved on restart of the program for partial recovery. Is this feasible? If so, what can I take a look at to get started?

UPDATE:
I read somewhere that shared memory on linux (I am on linux) is persistent, so I was thinking I might be able to save state snapshots periodically without the need of a helper process. Say for example, a continuously updating struct which I dump to shared memory every few seconds. The reason I would opt for shared memory instead of a file is purely for speed as state would be a lot of binary data.

Comment: Are you on Windows? If so you could just setup [WER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to collect dumps when crashes occur

Comment: this sounds like a flight recorder?

Comment: Shared memory does not survive a reboot. You will have to save the data in something more durable, like a file.

Comment: @RaymondChen "Reboot of the server" could also mean "restarting my server program" in a never-stopped-running OS.

Comment: If you only need to recover restart of the service (and not restart of the OS), you can use a helper process to hold onto the shared memory.

Comment: You may want to use shared memory to send critical objects to a second process, but that process should definitely be writing to disk. Trying to create a clothesline in limbo and hang your data on it is not going to work well. What if an out-of-memory condition kills both processes, or invalid data leaks in and crashes both?

Comment: @EdChum, not on windows but on linux

Comment: @RaymondChen, I edited my question, I should have said "restart of server after a crash" rather than reboot of the OS
also helper process could work (unless it crashed as well) - though I was hoping to not need one.

Comment: The phrase "restart of server" is still unclear. To most people, the server is the physical computer, so restarting the server means turning it off and on, which forces an OS restart. A quick web search on `shared memory persistent` quickly reveals that `shm_open` creates persistent shared memory (which on Linux is implemented in something similar to a RAM drive).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just an idea (not tried) on Uni*x like systems.

Do a fork(2) and send a SIGTRAP signal to this child process (or any [signal](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?signal+7) which creates a core dump).

Fork makes a copy of the original process environment. This will dump the full memory state. Then it can be analysed by gdb (or alike). Of course it is not for recovery...

You can create a `gdbinit` file and You can dump the variables from a script calling `gdb` with the core file.

Why the shared memory is needed? Is it not good to dump the state to disk?

---

I think this can be used for recover as well. Perl -u command line argument does similar thing. It parses the script file and dumps a core file. This core file can be used by [undump](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq3.html#How-can-I-make-my-Perl-program-run-faster?) program to load the core directly to the memory and start perl without the parsing phase.

Comment: I was wondering if using shared memory for this would be faster (both when writing the snapshots and reading them back in) - especially if the snapshots get big. If it's not that much harder than writing to file I would imagine opting for the shared memory approach would be better?

Comment: @Palace Chan: Actually you can read the memory of the process reading the `/proc/<pid>/mem` ([info about this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/how-do-i-read-from-proc-pid-mem-under-linux)). Or You can dump to shared memory (`/dev/shm`) which is usually mounted on `/lib/init/rw` (see `df`). Or You can implement a `new` operator for all classes You want to store in shared memory, but then You need to implement a low level memory manager. I suggest You to use the core dump version.